# SQL counterpart for the "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The SQL "in" clause will return values if anyone of the values inside the IN statement is matched. But what if we want to return a value where all the values inside the "IN"should be matched ?

Comment: How would that even work?

Comment: one value can't match all the values unless they are all the same. I think you need a concrete example of what you really mean.

Comment: If items are non-unique, that would be `WHERE 1=0`, because a single value cannot be equal to multiple non-equal items at the same time.

Comment: Isn't that what an `AND` is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` filter out records, eg.

```
SELECT yourColumn
FROM   tableName
WHERE  otherColumn IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP  BY yourColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3    -- <== the number of values in the WHERE clause
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Note that, unless `otherColumn` is guaranteed to be distinct within each group, you will need to `COUNT(DISTINCT otherColumn)`.